# Is this criterion for projective normality missing a hypothesis?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I proved the following:

> Let $S=S(X)$ be the homogeneous coordinate ring of a connected, normal closed subscheme of $\mathbf P^r_A$, where $A$ is a ring. Then $S$ is a domain, and $S^{\mathrm{int}}=S':=\bigoplus_{n\geq0}\Gamma(X,\mathscr O_X(n))$ is its integral closure.

It is then claimed:

> A closed subscheme $X\subset\mathbf P^r_A$ is projectively normal iff it is normal, and for every $n\geq0$ the natural map $\Gamma(\mathbf P^r,\mathscr O_{\mathbf P^r}(n))\rightarrow\Gamma(X,\mathscr O_X(n))$ is surjective.

My claim is that this is simply false if you don't assume either

1. $X$ is connected, OR
2. $A$ has exactly one closed point, OR
3. $A$ is not idempotented and the closed immersion $X\rightarrow\mathbf P_A^r$ is over $A$.

(Together with the hypotheses of the problem, both (2) and (3) imply (1), as discussed below.)

If you assume $X$ is connected, it is obvious. If you don't, I would like to explain what goes wrong if $A$ has more than one closed point. If $A$ has two closed points $\xi$ and $\eta$, then let $Y=\{\xi,\eta\}\subset\operatorname{Spec A}$ with the reduced induced structure corresponding to the ideal $I\subset A$. $Y$ is a normal closed subscheme and indeed $\mathbf P^r_Y\subset\mathbf P^r_A$ is the normal closed subscheme with inclusion induced by the natural map $A[x_0,\ldots,x_r]\twoheadrightarrow A/I[x_0,\ldots,x_r]$. But of course $S(\mathbf P^r_Y)=A/I[x_0,\ldots,x_r]$ is not an integrally closed domain.

It is a fact that $T:=\bigoplus_{n\geq0}\Gamma(\mathbf P^r,\mathscr O_{\mathbf P^r}(n))\cong A[x_0,\ldots,x_r]$. Then the induced map of graded rings $T\rightarrow\bigoplus_{n\geq0}\Gamma(X,\mathscr O_X(n))$ has image $S$. In our example, we would have that the natural map
$$\bigoplus_{n\geq0}\Gamma(\mathbf P^r_A,\mathscr O_{\mathbf P^r_A}(n))\rightarrow\bigoplus_{n\geq0}\Gamma(\mathbf P^r_Y,\mathscr O_{\mathbf P^r_Y}(n))$$
is simply $A[x_0,\ldots,x_r]\twoheadrightarrow A/I[x_0,\ldots,x_r]$.

If you assume $A$ is local (has exactly 1 closed point) then $X$ is automatically connected. Since if $X$ were not connected, $\Gamma(X,\mathscr O_X)\cong\Gamma(X_1,\mathscr O_{X_1})\times\Gamma(X_2,\mathscr O_{X_2})$ is an idempotented algebra, while $S_0\subset S(X)$ remains a local ring, hence cannot be idempotented. The image of $1\in S$ via the natural inclusion $S_0\subset\Gamma(X,\mathscr O_X)$ hits $1$ but not $1_{X_1}$ or $1_{X_2}$, hence cannot be surjective.

Likewise (3) implies $X$ connected by the same argument. If you drop the assumption that $A$ is not idempotented, then of course (3) is insufficient, because then $S(X)_0=A$ which is not a domain hence $S$ is not a domain, let alone a normal domain.

If you can establish that $X$ is connected in this way, then the result follows from the first statement, since then $S$ is a domain, and the image of the map 
$$\bigoplus_{n\geq0}\Gamma(\mathbf P^r_A,\mathscr O_{\mathbf P^r_A}(n))\twoheadrightarrow\bigoplus_{n\geq0}\Gamma(X,\mathscr O_X(n))$$
(surjective by hypothesis) is simply $S(X)$, which then coincides with its integral closure by the above.

Please tell me, have I missed anything?

Comment: I think your hypotheses might be enough: If $X$ is not connected, then $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ would contain more than one copy of $A$, hence you would not have a surjection from $\Gamma(\mathbf{P}^n,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbf{P^n}}) = A$.

Comment: @TakumiMurayama Are you suggesting that my example above contradicting your claim is in error? If so, how?

Comment: Nevermind, my argument works if $A$ is a field (or more generally, if $A \cong \Gamma(\mathbf{P}^n,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbf{P}^n}) \to \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is injective). Your argument seems correct otherwise. Anyway, if you are doing this for Hartshorne, II, Exercise 5.14(d), then it asks you to prove your claim as a corollary to Exercise 5.14(a), and so I think the wording of the problem suggests you are allowed to take $X$ to be connected.

Comment: @TakumiMurayama Actually, we would like the criterion to take care of the connectedness assumption. So we prefer to assume A local, as discussed above. Part (a) holds for any affine base, part (b) holds for any affine Nagata base, and as discussed (d) can be solved over any local affine base.  Cheers